# How to access all video files from sdcard to my videoplayer app in android

Tags: android

Require code to access all video files on sd card....

Mainvdo.java

```
public class Mainvdo extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video);      
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        //Require code to access all video files on sd card....

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will give you path to all the video files on sd card in a list

```
private void findAllVideoFiles()
{       
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor videoCursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (videoCursor != null) {
        while (videoCursor.moveToNext()) {

            mediaNameList.add(videoCursor.getString(videoCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            mediaPathList.add(videoCursor.getString(0));
            //System.out.println("Video "+videoCursor.getString(videoCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        }
        videoCursor.close();
    }
}
```